# Notepad++ and stdint.h types

Tags: c, notepad++, stdint

Notepad++ C and C++ builtin languages, do not recognize stdint types (uint8_t etc) and as such these types do not get colored.

Is there a way to extract the builtin language, so that the stdint types are inserted, whithout having to create a new language from scratch?

Comment: Why should npp treat those types differently from any other types defined in the standard library?

Comment: Because one could write his code using only stdint types, which unlike C core types, do not get colored.

Comment: The "stdint types" you mention are mere *typedefs*, nothing else; that's why they are not "recognized". Fortunately, Notepad++ is fully open source, so you can download, adjust to personal taste, and re-compile it.

Comment: All above comments are correct. I'm not testing the validity of npp chosing not to paint the stdint types. I'm just trying to beautify / make my code more visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to *Settings* > *Style Configurator*, and then to *C* / *C++* languages, and then to the *TYPE WORD* style. There you can add new types `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, `int8_t` etc in the *User-defined keywords* textbox.

Comment: Yeap, your advice solved my problem easily without hassle! Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

\Notepad++\plugins\APIs\

thats what you're lookig for

Comment: Thanks, there are the builtin .xml files!
It need some work, because the files can't be directly imported but I guess it can be done.